# How to remove trailing zeroes in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a column that is in INT type. I want to remove all the trailing zeroes and only have the number. The example below, should follow be: 3,10,20,20. I cannot have the 4 zeroes at the end.

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: `3`, `3.0000` and even `0.3e1` are the same values. How you *see* it depends on the display settings of the application, not the data. So the question is not clear: `3.000` is an integer. The right place to deal with data display task is at the application side. If you have any issues with calculations or other operations, then please describe what is that issue.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70183325/removing-trailing-zeroes-after-decimal-snowflake

Answer (score 1):

You could try casting your numeric data to integer, e.g.

```sql
SELECT AS_INTEGER(col) AS col
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TRUNCATE` or `RTRIM` function as below

```
TRUNCATE(Fieldname)
RTRIM(Fieldname,'.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

the 3dp is how floating point numbers print, thus you can [cast to number](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_decimal.html)  `SELECT column_name::number FROM table`

If your data is a string/varient type, and not all values stored in your column always casts cleanly, in Snowflake you can hit error, with the `TO_NUMBER` or `::number` forms, thus `[TRY_TO_NUMBER][2]` form should be used.