# Removing trailing zeroes after decimal Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been trying to remove trailing zeroes from a numeric column after the decimal. For example:

```
0.978219150000 -> 0.97821915
0.650502591918 -> 0.650502591918
0.975479450000 -> 0.97547945
```

The data type is NUMBER(38,12). Is there any way to remove the trailing zeroes as I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to cast to float:

```
create or replace table test (a NUMBER(38,12));
insert into test values (0.97821915), (0.650502591918), (0.975479450000);

select a from test;
+----------------+
|              A |
|----------------|
| 0.978219150000 |
| 0.650502591918 |
| 0.975479450000 |
+----------------+

select a::float from test;
+--------------+
|     A::FLOAT |
|--------------|
| 0.97821915   |
| 0.6505025919 |
| 0.97547945   |
+--------------+
```

However, depending what you want to achieve, using floating number might not be a good idea due to potential rounding issues.

**UPDATE:**

I tried the regexp version, not sure if I missed any test case or not:

```
create or replace table test (a NUMBER(38,12));
insert into test values 
    (0.97), 
    (0.650502591918), 
    (0.975479450000), 
    (10000), 
    (1450000), 
    (12.2000), 
    (14.0200);

select regexp_replace(
    a::varchar, 
    '^([0-9]+)$|' ||
    '^([0-9]+)\.0*$|' ||
    '^([0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,}[1-9])0*$|' ||
    '^([0-9]+\.[1-9])0*$', '\\1\\2\\3\\4'
) as a from test;

+----------------+
| A              |
|----------------|
| 0.97           |
| 0.650502591918 |
| 0.97547945     |
| 10000          |
| 1450000        |
| 12.2           |
| 14.02          |
+----------------+
```

Where:

```
^([0-9]+)$                   -> will cover the integer like 10000
^([0-9]+)\.0*$               -> will cover integer like 10.000000
^([0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,}[1-9])0*$ -> will cover 14.0200000
^([0-9]+\.[1-9])0*$.         -> will cover 12.20000 or 0.97540000
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is just a formatting/display issue, you can use the to_varchar() function with a fixed decimal format string:

```
select 123.45::number(38,12); -- 123.450000000000
select to_varchar(123.45::number(38,12), '99G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999D999999999999'); -- 123.45
```

Since the format string is a bit long, it may make sense to put it in a UDF to make it more compact in SQL:

```
create or replace function DISPLAY_38_12(N number(38,12))
returns varchar
language sql
as
$$
to_varchar(123.45::number(38,12), '99G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999D999999999999')
$$;

select DISPLAY_38_12(123.45::number(38,12));
```